# Database design for custom objects for SaaS application

Tags: postgresql, database-design, entity-framework-core, saas

I’m looking forward to creating a multitenant-based SASS application. I have defined database design like each tenant using different databases (Postgres) with standard objects(tables) like contact, and accounts. So far clean, I can see many SaaS application supports Custom Object(tables), where customer can create their own objects in real-time and required columns. I would want to support the same. Could someone please explain the backend logic behind that? How can we add new tables for custom objects in the database and refresh the DbContext entity at runtime?

Note: I’m aware for custom fields, many choice JSON-type columns in Postgres, it opens ways to add as many custom columns as JSON type in existing tables. But don’t find any recommended way to do custom object support.

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't really support adding tables at runtime.  You can use ADO.NET queries to work with tables whose schemas aren't known at design-time.

Comment: Thanks, David Browne, I hope this is the recommended way to do so. Or any other alternative ways to create schemas at run time, and then query new tables directly using SQL commands.

Comment: Having user-created entities is a big and complex feature.

Comment: Yes, I understood the complexity. I'm trying to understand the approaches we can follow to achieve this feature like you mentioned ADO.NET queries.